# Handling paste event for a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is an example DIV where when selected and paste (`CTRL`+`V`) it will paste a text or image on the div:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="capture" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; " 
onpaste='handlepaste(this, event)'></div
```

The problem here is my application will hide this `div` and essentially user cannot find where it is located. So is there a way that paste event is triggered and that the text or image gets pasted on this div even not selected in the page?

**Update:**

What I mean, I will make the div hidden for a reason that I don't need my app to display the image or text being captured. It just need it to get the captured image or text later.

Comment: not in jquery?you want only javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your div doesn't contain anything initially then its will not appear. so you can do either of the following :

1. Set the width and hight of the div to be appear on screen and give some differnt background and add the text `&nbsp;` as default text
2. you can set the `onpaste='handlepaste(this, event)'` on outer div and insted of this you can pass the target div id or you can handle the target inside the handlepaste method.

like 
 `function handlepaste(event){ var target = $('#capture'); ...... }`

Comment: I updated my question, I think it had some vague grammar to point out the real question

Comment: Initially you can set the style of div `style="display: none;"` and can perform paste action on parent div as mentioned in point 2. Once the action is done the content will be placed on that div and you will be free to use it at any point of time.